# Filtering Approvers in SOAP retrieve request

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap

I would like to filter a SOAP request for AccountUsers where the role equals APPROVER. Here's the SOAP envelope without a filter:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
           <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
              <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
              <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pass</wsse:Password>
           </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
     </soapenv:Header>
     <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
           <RetrieveRequest>
              <ObjectType>AccountUser</ObjectType>
              <Properties>Name</Properties>
              <Properties>Email</Properties>
              <Properties>Roles</Properties>
           </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
     </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

This returns all users and their roles (snippet below)

```
    <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
        <RequestID>668aec01-1022-406e-82d5-b446ffd89beb</RequestID>
        <Results xsi:type="AccountUser">
            <Client>
                <ID>10699999</ID>
            </Client>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <ID>10656984</ID>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
            <Name>Sam Sample</Name>
            <Email>email@companylcom</Email>
            <Delete>0</Delete>
            <Roles>
                <Role>
                    <Client>
                        <ID>10659964</ID>
                        <CreatedBy>34649</CreatedBy>
                        <ModifiedBy>34649</ModifiedBy>
                        <EnterpriseID>10659964</EnterpriseID>
                    </Client>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <CreatedDate>2013-12-27T13:03:33.32</CreatedDate>
                    <ModifiedDate>2013-12-27T13:03:33.32</ModifiedDate>
                    <ObjectID>68057e44-f76e-e311-987e-0025b3d7f36a</ObjectID>
                    <CustomerKey>APPROVER</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>Add Users to Account</Name>
                    <Description>Add Users to Account</Description>
                    <IsPrivate>false</IsPrivate>
                    <IsSystemDefined>false</IsSystemDefined>
                </Role>
```

I would like to filter this to only include results where Role.CustomerKey equals APPROVER but I can't figure out what this simple filter would be. Is someone able to provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
           <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
              <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
              <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pass</wsse:Password>
           </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
     </soapenv:Header>
     <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
           <RetrieveRequest>
              <ObjectType>AccountUser</ObjectType>
              <Properties>Name</Properties>
              <Properties>Email</Properties>
              <Properties>Roles</Properties>
              <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                 <Property>Roles</Property>
                 <SimpleOperator>like</SimpleOperator>
                 <Value>APPROVER</DateValue>
              </Filter>
           </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
     </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi Kelly, thanks. I have just tried this now (note I fixed your filter value to `<Value>APPROVER</Value>`) but this returns error: `<OverallStatus>Error: The Filter Property Roles does not match with the fields of the view</OverallStatus>`. Perhaps this is because we have an array of roles? You can [view the result without filter](http://digital-logic.s3.amazonaws.com/temp/AccountUserResponse.xml) if that helps.

Comment: I thought I corrected both sides of that copy paste :) I am guessing you also tried Roles.Role.CustomerKey?  I have no idea if that works, I so rarely filter on sub-nodes.

Comment: Hi Kelly, that does not work either. It returns `<OverallStatus>Error: The Filter Property Roles.Role.CustomerKey does not match with the fields of the view</OverallStatus>`. I'll escalate this through the channel and let you know what the solution is.

Comment: I eventually received a response back from ExactTarget and they explained that it's not possible to filter where Role.CustomerKey equals APPROVER at this time.

Comment: Would you be sure to add as an answer what you eventually did do, and then mark this as answered. Thanks for your help!

Comment: We are parsing the SOAP response and filtering where Role.CustomerKey equals APPROVER. We're actually doing this by transforming the XML response to JSON, but it could be also achieved by XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

The solution/workaround is to parse the SOAP Response and find AccountUsers that have `<CustomerKey>APPROVER</CustomerKey>` values in the response.